# EC2 instance web access ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error. HTTP port is open

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

In Ec2 instance, HTTP port is open in security group . Still when i am trying to access the public IP through web browser (chrome,safari) its showing ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

I am able to ssh the instance .

when i have removed the permissions from security group its showing connection timed out but after giving permissions its saying connection refused.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to provide more information? For example, how are you trying to connect to the instance — are you accessing it via a web browser via the Internet? Did you install a web server on the Amazon EC2 instance? If you login to the instance and run `curl localhost`, does the website appear (this test avoids networking issues)? Can you even SSH into the instance? If you can provide more information, we will be able to provide a better answer.